# Vue root instance being duplicated after recent patch

Tags: gulp, browserify, vue.js, laravel-elixir

Since `v1.0.18`, Vue.js has been duplicating my root component, as evidenced by a simple example of putting an `alert('hey!')` inside of the `data()` function. Since the root component gets duplicated, every child of it also is duplicated, resulting in twice the AJAX requests as necessary, etc. Curiously, the state actually persists across both (every user is duplicated in the user array), but that's beside the point.

The only part of the setup I can think to blame would be between `gulp`, `browserify`, or `laravel-elixir-vueify`.Can anyone think of a reason why these newer versions of Vue might cause an issue of the Vue components being duplicated in my app?

Code can be viewed on the Vue forum page [here](http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/3793/root-instance-being-duplicated-following-patch-1-0-18). Thanks!

Comment: Check out this thread [https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2687](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2687)

Comment: if you put your alert in the `created` hook it is still launched twice?

Comment: Definitely a bug, nice find.

Comment: @bartlomieju Thanks for finding that, I'll stay posted in what happens and reply back to this question with the answer.  


@Yerko I'm not sure, I've never had a use for `created()` let me check when I get back home. According to the bug on Git shown above, I'd guess not.  


@Jeff not so sure about _where_ the bug is though, whether it be in `vue`, `laravel-elixir-vueify`, `gulp`, `browserify`... that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug introduced in Vuejs`v1.0.18` and a commit on Git is fixing it.

My entire component wasn't being duplicated, just the `data()` hook was being called twice.

Just as a PSA: don't send AJAX requests (like I was) from within `data()`, use `activate()` instead!

[GitHub bug thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/2689)